# Is there a way to gauge how environmentally (un)friendly popular genAIs are?

Tags: comparison, environment

The environmentally conscious user may prefer a genAI which is less harmful to the environment, such as those with less CO₂ emissions.  I was reading [*How to Make Generative AI Greener*](https://hbr.org/2023/07/how-to-make-generative-ai-greener) which suggests server location is a big factor in whether or not a genAI uses green energy, and it explains how a large amount of the CO₂ emissions occur during training, so it's not easy for the typical user to determine which genAI is better environmentally.  So...

**Question**: Is there a way to gauge how environmentally (un)friendly popular genAIs are?

Maybe there are some kind of "AI watch" groups which rank genAIs according to their CO₂ emissions or other environmental factors.  Or maybe certain genAI companies publish environmental impact reports (perhaps as required by law).

Comment: Related: https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/111/12

Answer (score 5):

> Maybe there are some kind of "AI watch" groups which rank genAIs according to their CO₂ emissions or other environmental factors.

There are some surveys e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.02001:

[image]

> perhaps as required by law

I'm not aware of any such laws. I don't think there are any.